# How does the "overloaded" trick for calling visit on variants in C++ actually work?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I've seen code like the following popping up in C++17 codebases and have started using it myself:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> var = "foo";
    std::visit(
        overloaded{
            [](int) {std::cout << "int\n"; },
            [](std::string) {std::cout << "string\n"; }
        },
        var
    );

}
```

and am trying to understand what `overloaded` is actually doing. Without using variadic templates I believe the above expands to:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
struct overloaded : T, U {
    using T::operator();
    using U::operator();
};

template <typename T, typename U>   // <- 
overloaded(T, U)->overloaded<T, U>; // <- what is this?
```

I understand the definition of `struct overloaded`: it is inheriting from what will be two lambdas which will have `operator()` defined by virtue of being lambdas and saying to use those `operator()`s as the function call operators of `overloaded`. However, I don't even know what the other two lines *are* in terms of the semantics of C++: they seem to be making it so you can construct a `struct overloaded` from arbitrary lambdas or something like that.

Comment: https://www.bfilipek.com/2019/02/2lines3featuresoverload.html

Comment: https://dev.to/tmr232/that-overloaded-trick-overloading-lambdas-in-c17

Comment: thanks. reading now

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm confused. The proposed target doesn't address the OP's primary question.

Comment: @cigien Yes, it does.

Comment: yeah it answers the primary question. the two lines i did not understand are a template deduction guide.

Comment: Ok, that's good. The title is a bit misleading, but I suppose there's not really a better way to ask the question.